# Replace png image in .bundle crash the app in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, bundle

I am using `jsqmessagesviewcontroller` chat library using pod in my project.

I want to replace bubble image in`JSQMessagesAssets.bundle` but when I replace the image my app is crashing.

Can anyone help me to sort out how to replace file in .bundle assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly open the .bundle file, just go to .bundle folder, right click it and use show package content. There try to replace your file.

Cheers

Comment: I am doing same. but it is not working. Do you thing this happens due to pods.

Comment: Are you using the same image name and extension as you had for the bubble image already. And moreover try to put the breakpoint where you are accessing this image. You will come to know if the image name is coming nil or not. This will help you to debug your issue. Pod is nothing to do with this. Just make sure that you don't have new file in red color and the file name is correct.

Comment: The file name is correct  and not in red i have also checked the path to other images in this bundle that is also same and during debugging image comes nil.